# Android not finding file path Unity 5

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I am using the streaming assets folder to hold some information that I need to run my program. Here is how I am determining the filepath to use:

```
    // Location of the top part of the query
    public string fileLocation_queryTop = "/Bro/bro_Headers_TOP.json";        

    // We are on android
    if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        assetPath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets";
    }
    // We are on iPhone
    else if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {
        assetPath = Application.dataPath + "/Raw";
    }
    // We are on mac or windows
    else
    {
        assetPath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets";
    }

    _query_TOP = File.ReadAllText(assetPath + fileLocation_queryTop);
```

This works fine on Windows, but I am trying to build for Android today.

Here is error that I am getting

[image]

I got the info on what path to use from the [Unity docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is the `Application.streamingAssetsPath`. You can find more information about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html).

Since you are on Android, you will have to use the [**WWW**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class from Unity to retrieve your files.

**EDIT:**
Following [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) you simply have to adjust the file name and store the result in your `_query_TOP` variable.

```
private IEnumerator LoadFile()
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "file.txt");

    if(filePath.Contains("://"))
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
        yield return www;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            _query_TOP = www.text;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _query_TOP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I need to use WWW for iOS as well?

Comment: You can always try using `System.IO`, but since assets are also packed on iOS (at least I think) I'd say yes. Also using **WWW** is often a good idea :)

Comment: Hey, I still can't get this to work out. 

`if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            assetPath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";
        }
        else
        {
            assetPath = "file:///" + Application.streamingAssetsPath;
        }

        // Load in the top query
        WWW www = new WWW(assetPath + "/file.txt");
        yield return www;

        // If there was no error...
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            _query_TOP = www.text;
        }`

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to mention I updated my answer to give you a proper example. Sorry for being late.